# why this warning in this java program

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

i need help i am getting error like

```
Description                               Resource        Path                Location    Type  
Resource leak: 'input' is never closed    Methods.java    /piyush/src/piyush  line 7      Java Problem
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Methods {


 public static void main(String[] args){
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("what is your name ");
   String yourName = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("hello " + yourName);
 }


 }
```

Comment: I think message is clear. What part of *'input' is never closed* you don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close streams after their use. In your case, add

```
input.close();
```

just after the last `System.out.println()` to close your `Scanner` and get rid of the warning.

Comment: In fact he should close in a `finally` block.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, then he uses a Java version from the dark ages. [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @m0skit0, You mean in a `try{...}finally{input.close();}`?

Comment: what if i have to use later scanner will it work?

Comment: @PiyushKashyap , No. You've freed whatever resources it was consuming. You'll have to create a new `Scanner`. Also,read the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Tom Java 6 is most popular version (because of Android mostly)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a error, its a warning. Errors/Exceptions are if there is some mistake in your code (compilation errors) or if something goes wrong while execution of program (runtime exceptions).

You should always close streams that you use, in your case `Scanner input`:-

```
input.close();
```

This warning can be ignored and it should work fine without the `close()` , but it is a good practice to close resources after usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the scanner to release any system resources.  Use

```
input.close();
```

as the last line in your code.  See [`Closeable.close()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close%28%29) for some more info.

Comment: He should close in a `finally` block to be more correct.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, that would be the correct way of doing it - but really he needs to add proper error handling anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the `Scanner` and it would be fine in this case, but this will close the underlying `System.in` input stream and prevent you from accepting input in case you later read from the standard input stream.

Comment: Whats wrong with closing the underlying input stream ?

Comment: If he has no more use of Scanner, he should close it, not ignore the warning.

Comment: Fixing errors tends to be a lot more effective than suppressing/ignoring them.

Comment: @Mustafasabir Closing `System.in` won't allow the user to accept input after closing the scanner.

Comment: @manouti I don't see he's going to use it any more in the posted code.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, hence the "in case" in the answer.